Wireless connection not showing up after fresh install Debian 12 (Gnome)
I have a dual booted Debian 12(Gnome) setup with Windows 11 on my Acer laptop. After installation Wifi doesnt show up in settings. Only wired connection works and am not able to find wifi connection.
lspci | grep network
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 30)

lspci | grep net
2d:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

I have network-manager installed and also checked network/interface but still couldnt figure out.
I checked dmesg, I see some some errors related to wifi, some part of the log is below.
[    5.421475] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.422237] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[    5.422976] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[    9.258785] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    9.272031] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2

I also have this error in dmesg, but I am not sure if this is related to wifi
[    1.214738] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead


[    0.411670] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[    0.411677] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.TXHC.RHUB.SS01._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)


[    1.845836] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[    1.845856] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS01._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[    1.845900] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[    1.845929] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS01._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)

Thanks in advance..:)

Does your kernel see the wifi adapter, is it listed in lspci, are modules for it loaded lsmod?

@tink I tried "lspci | grep -i wireless" but I see nothing

@John it is 6.1.0-21-amd64 which is latest one

@itsmepvr please put all info into the question ... a comment is not the place for it

what is the wireless device called in Windows, i.e. in Device Manager - you should be able to get the make/model at least, though, the Harware ID's would be more useful information

did you research that first error? failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin ... I did, and the first link is https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=149817 - not Debian 12, but probably still relevant

@JaromandaX Thanks, I tried that now, the error failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin doesnt show up now. But I still have same issue. I have the update the question.

I have finally found a solution here. I upgraded kernel using backports and it worked. But still I was not able to connect to home Wifi which led me to this.
I made minor changes to /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
From options iwlwifi 11n_disable=0 to options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
Also, from the previous comments this also worked for failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin
Thanks everyone for investing their time and helping me out.
